# What is a way to return a list of most common item in a list of lists?

Tags: python, sorting

If I had a list such as

```
[['dog','cat'],['bird','cat'],['dog','squirrel']]
```

, I am trying to find a way that I would return the most common elements at index [0] of the list among all the sublists and return this as a list.

So if I applied it to the list on top, it'd return:

```
 ['dog','bird']
```

as only those two were at position 0 for their lists and dog was more common.

Comment: What have __you__ tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "most common"? How many of the most common? Your example returns all of them; why isn't it leaving out the least common element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? You can specify how many you want in most_common.

```
import collections

animals = [['dog','cat'],['bird','cat'],['dog','squirrel']]
print(list(x[0] for x in collections.Counter(x[0] for x in animals).most_common()))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly but my web server is being annoying and not accepting it. It works fine on Terminal but not on the site. Is there any workaround solution? It just won't load the page but it doesn't error when I try on server.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count strings and use the [`Counter.most_common()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method to get the most-frequent item:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(item[0] for item in yourlist)
print counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> yourlist = [['dog','cat'],['bird','cat'],['dog','squirrel']]
>>> counts = Counter(item[0] for item in yourlist)
>>> print counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that you mean to have the `unique and common` elements from the list index 0??

```
lst = [['dog','cat'],['bird','cat'],['dog','squirrel']];
new_lst = list(set([x[0] for x in lst]))
print new_lst
```

Output:

```
['dog', 'bird']
```